# How can i pass information from my master thread to worker threads in node clustering?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node app with clustering. And i would like to keep the number of db connections down to one but i could not find a way to pass the db instance from the master thread to the children.

The code looks like this.

```
const express = require('express'),
cluster = require('cluster'),
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length,
exec = require('child_process').exec,
app = express(),
dbInstance = require('./mongodb').getInstance;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
    }
 else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    app.listen(4000);
}
```

the db instance is called for all the workers and i end up with 8 instances. How can i do it just once in the master?

Also if i kill one of the workers will the dbConnection still be alive or will it auto close?